# org.json.JSONObject.getNumber() throws "NoSuchMethodError" when called using unittest

Tags: java, json, unit-testing, junit4

While unit testing, I noticed some strang behaviour when calling JSONObject.getNumber() when running unittests. This is the error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.Number org.json.JSONObject.getNumber(java.lang.String)
```

This is the code:

```
Number logId;
logId = jsonObject.getNumber("logId");
```

For my own implementation, I could just use this one:

```
logId = jsonObject.getInt("logId");
```

But I am really wondering what I was missing when trying to unit test with JSONObject.getNumber(). Why is the getNumber() method missing?

**Edit 2019-12-20 13:59**
I am using maven groupID 'org.json', artifactId 'json', version '20190722'. I call the `.getNumber()` on a custom made `new JSONObject().put(stuff).put(stuff)`

Answer (score 0):

Please check you json version. i am able to find jsonObject.getNumber() in version: '20180813'

Here is the gradle dependency for your reference

```
compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180813'
```

This is the implementation class find in that jar

```
/**
     * Get the Number value associated with a key.
     *
     * @param key
     *            A key string.
     * @return The numeric value.
     * @throws JSONException
     *             if the key is not found or if the value is not a Number
     *             object and cannot be converted to a number.
     */
    public Number getNumber(String key) throws JSONException {
        Object object = this.get(key);
        try {
            if (object instanceof Number) {
                return (Number)object;
            }
            return stringToNumber(object.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new JSONException("JSONObject[" + quote(key)
                    + "] is not a number.", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already did that.. I also found the implementation of the class and it does compile. However, when unittesting, it still says it can't find the method. Btw, the getNumber() method I call on a mocked object that I create with "new JSONObject().put(stuff).put(stuff).put(stuff)"